# Why Java program starts with in a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

It might sound trivial but I wanted to get this doubt cleared.

Why java program starts with in a thread ?  Why doesn't it simply start as a process without main thread from where we can create own threads. Does people use main thread as a Master thread which control other threads in the production code ? or do they use separate Master thread other than the main thread ?

Comment: please drop a comment for downvote.

Comment: Some people can't admit that there are things they don't know.  When they see a question or an answer that they don't understand, they have to downvote it to validate their own self-image.  Some people have narrow ideas about what kind of questions are appropriate for SO, and what are not.  Some people get pissy when they see a question or an answer that is not written in perfect English.  Some people are just jerks.

Comment: I agree, downvote was uncalled for. This is a reasonable, though basic question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding here.

Java programs start in a thread because you must have a Thread. Everything executing in a program executes in a Thread.

Even single-threaded programs have a Thread - they just only have one.

Starting a Process without starting a Thread would be meaningless. The Process couldn't do anything because the only way to do things is to execute instructions and the only way to execute instructions is in a Thread...

As to the Master thread, that is entirely down to the architecture of the program. Some programs do have a Master thread (although it's actually fairly rare) but many others do not. Your main thread might start up a number of other threads then exit immediately or it may remain forever controlling the overall flow of the program.

The important thing to remember is that as far as Java is concerned that main thread is not special in any way apart from the fact that it starts it running when the program starts. That thread can start, pause, stop, exit and the program will keep running. The program only ends when `exit` is called or every non-daemon thread has ended.

Comment: Is it the same case with C family languages too ?

Comment: @HakunaMatata Most object oriented and procedural languages (especially those with threading as a designed-in concept) work along these lines, although details may vary.

Comment: @HakunaMatata, it's not a language thing, it's an operating system thing...  Not even that, it's a computer architecture thing.  "Thread" is a new name for an idea that is as old as computers themselves.  Nobody knew that it needed a name until we started writing programs that had more than one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Java code only executes in Threads. If it runs, it runs in a Thread. That might look like overhead at first glance, but it actually keeps the VM simple (well, simpler). The VM doesn't have to differentiate between "runs in Thread" and "runs in main process".

The Thread object also keeps information on the execution of that Thread, like used CPU time etc. It is associated with a stack, with monitors (synchronized objects) etc. If the main Thread weren't a Thread, the VM would have to manage all this differently, but consistent over Threads and the main process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean java Swing applications? Command line java applications don't start a new thread by default, and everything just runs in the main thread. Swing uses a separate thread to handle UI events (the notorious Event Dispatch Thread - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

it is wrong that java program start with in a thread. when java program going to be run then it is a single process and to produce the final output to user JVM divides its task into different thread  to utilize the CPU cycle and memory management in more optimized way.TO run a single program JVM needs to do some action before executing that program. if all action is a process then its not a good utilization of memory. beacuse we can't provide different memory space for same thing to do.